# Braintree "Subscriptions" and "Add Ons"

Tags: node.js, braintree

**Question 1:**

For braintree is it correct to use Add Ons with number of billing cycle of 1 to collect deposit?

I'm trying to implement subscriptions where user will pay a monthly fee. However, during first time sign-up I would like the user to place a deposit.

```
gateway.subscription.create({
    paymentMethodToken: result.customer.paymentMethods[0].token,
    planId: "platinumPlanID"
}, function (err, result) {
    console.log('subscription result:', result);
    console.log('subscription err:', err);
    res.send(result)
});
```

[image]

**Question 2:**

How to simulate if the subscription is working accordingly?

**Question 3:**

How to retrieve user's payment history for monthly subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact
[support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you wish to have the initial subscription amount and the deposit charged under the same transaction, then using the 1 time add on as you have mentioned will achieve this.

Another way to achieve this would be to charge the deposit as a 1 time transaction (as opposed to a subscription) by using the [transaction.sale](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale) call. Then, if this initial transaction is successful, you can create the subscription.

Either of these options will work, so it is a matter of a personal preference between splitting the deposit and the subscription, or having them go through on the same transaction.

For question 2: You can test out your subscription logic by using our sandbox environment and creating subscriptions within the sandbox.

For question 3: You can reference the [transactions array](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription#transactions) within the [subscription object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription) to review past transactions for a specific subscription. You can also run a subscription search within the Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks @bbusby. Guess I'll go with the add on approach, since I just need to create a subscription to make it work. For question 2, I've managed to create a subscription in the sandbox, however how can I fast forward the time to the second billing cycle to test out if things are working? (e.g. to confirm the date of the billing cycle by retrieving the transaction history for a particular user)

Comment: While there is no way to fast forward time in the sandbox, you should be able to retrieve the subscription object (example: by parsing the subscriptions array from the payment method object) and viewing the information you wish to test there. Another idea would be to create a subscription with the first billing date set for the next day (in case you wanted to test automated handling of the object).